# Rails equivalent to Django's "choices"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-select

I know there is no real equivalent in Rails but my question is mostly about best practice...

In Django, if you want to limit a model field to a limited set of choices, you would do something like this (in your model):

```
COLOR_CHOICES = (('B', 'Blue'), ('R', 'Red'))
item_color = models.CharField(choices=COLOR_CHOICES)
```

From my (basic) understanding of Rails, I can achieve something similar, for example, by using a select tag in the forms dealing with adding/editing that model...

My question however is, where would it be appropriate to declare the "choices" hash (again I'm guessing here that a hash is what I need?). Basically I just want it to be easily re-usable in any forms where I might need to present those choices, and when it comes to validating at the model level.

Any help/tips would be appreciated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On the validation side of things, probably validates_inclusion_of is what you need:

```
class Coffee < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_inclusion_of :size, :in => %w(small medium large),
    :message => "%{value} is not a valid size"
end
```

As for generating the helper, you can try something like:

```
class Coffee < ActiveRecord::Base
  @@coffe_size = %w(small medium large)

  validates_inclusion_of :size, :in => @@coffe_size,
    :message => "%{value} is not a valid size"

   def self.coffee_size_options
       @@coffe_size.map{ |z| [z,z]} 
   end
end
```

And then in some helper:

```
<%= select(:coffee, :size, Coffee.coffee_size_options) %>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use enum

```
class Coffee < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum color: [ :blue, :red, :green ]
end
```

More information here : https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.4.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html

Comment: This should now be the accepted answer. `enum` is definitely the way to go in modern rails apps.

Comment: I used Django extensively and just moved to Rails. While `choices` are the way in Django, I think this approach should be the approved answer. As this is the better practice in Rails.

Answer (score 0):

2 years later, there's a better option: values_for

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :brand
  values_for :brand, :has=>[:ford, :chevy, :dodge], :add=>[:constants]

  def doStuff
    # Now you can...
    Car.brands # [:ford, :chevy, :dodge]
    Car::BRAND_FORD # "ford"
    myCar = Car.new(:brand=>Car::BRAND_FORD)
    myCar.valid? # true
    myCar.brand= "duck."
    myCar.valid? # false
  end
end
```

Comment: can you link to the documentation for this method? it looks great but my google-fu is failing me.